# Angular spring boot integration security error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular8, jwt, spring-security-rest

I'm building a spring boot application with JWT security and integrate it to an Angular webApp.

I'm running the app using this command : java - jar myapp.jar, when i open the browser it show me this error :

[image]

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/token/*", "/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>ng</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/ui</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>build</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: You're trying to load a resource at the path /Home. What do you expect to happen? Do you have any controller or filter mapped to that path? If not, a 404 not found is the correct answer, isn't it?

Comment: But the Angular application can only start once the browser has downloaded the index.html page from the server. So the server must be configured to serve the index.html file for the /Home path (and for all the other paths of the Angular application). https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: It's a path in my angular app to load the AppComponent